# How to filter rows using a drop down menu in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've created this spreadsheet in google sheets, I'd like to create a button to easily filter the information showing me one specific row, and/or one (or many) columns. I've been looking around but I didn't find this information easily, could somebody help me please?

Thanks a lot for your help, here is the link if you can have a look

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ytY1IfxRlujad2w6D_B1ggsUwqiwT6Vu_CHd-mY2DG4/edit?usp=sharing

I had a look at drop down menus, create filters, smart chips, but I'm not very familiar with excel and / or the smart functions in google sheets

Comment: I think it would be better if you could provide an example of what you are trying to do, like a real scenario with the expected result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'd like to have a dropdown menu where I could select at least one of the categories in the first column then it would only show that row, so I can easily look at the information instead of going down in the file manually

Comment: I found a website with some tips and added a drop down menu but I don't know which formula to add in order to show the right information in columns B, C and D

Comment: I was just checking the file you shared but it seems like this is already working as expected, is that the case? If so, could you share the solution you found with the community so that you can leave a record in case someone else has a  similar question can find your answer and get an idea of how to solve it?

Comment: Yes it works as expected, I think someone accessed the file and input the formula, but I don't know who that is.. the formula is =iferror( filter(B4:D, A4:A = A3, len(A4:A)) )

Comment: Posted the formula as a community Wiki for future references.

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing this answer as a community wiki, since the answer was posted in the comments section, in order to provide a proper response to the question.

According to [Salvador C.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21305525/salvador-c) the correct formula to use in Google Sheets is the following:

```
=iferror( filter(B4:D, A4:A = A3, len(A4:A)) )
```